# Copying file pointer into array

Tags: c, arrays

Here, I am trying to read from a text file, copy this file into an array, then I want to write the array to another text file. This is not copying into the array at all. I am just getting blank values when I print.

```
int main(void)
{
   char char_array[50];
   char copied_array[50];

    //int n = 2;

    FILE* fpointer = fopen("hello_world.txt", "r");

    FILE* fpointer2 = fopen("copyhello.txt", "w");

    for(int i = 0;i < 50; i++)
    {
        fread(&char_array, sizeof(char), 1, fpointer);

        copied_array[i] = char_array[i];

    }

    for(int j = 0;j < 50; j++)
    {
        printf("char_array: %c\n", copied_array[j]);
    }

    fclose(fpointer);
    fclose(fpointer2);

}
```

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: Declarations matter.  Your code looks suspicious, but we can't tell you for sure whether it's valid.  Have you consulted your compiler?  If you want our help then present a [mcve].  Or if your code in fact does not compile, then at least a Minimal & Complete Example.  And no, that does *not* mean the whole program from which this is drawn.

Comment: all of the code is here... https://pastebin.com/vQKbqVWx
I was just trying to figure out if the copying into the array was valid.

Comment: Any code you want us to consider here goes into the question itself.  Use the handy "edit" link underneath it.  And again, no, we *don't* want the whole program.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to recreate it into smaller code.

Comment: ```char_array[i]``` is a ```char *```, but ```&char_array``` is a ```char **```

Comment: This is not the only failure in the above code: `char* char_array[50];` is an array of pointers of char, what you want is an array of char like `char char_array[50]` , etc.

Comment: You want to write into the i-th array entry in each iteration, so change to `fread(&char_array[i], ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code. hope this becomes clearer :)
Note you're using fread/fwrite - compare with fgets/fputs for strings.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

#define BUFSIZE 50
// memory size 'plus one' to leave room for a string-terminating '\0'
#define BUFMEMSIZE (BUFSIZE+1)

const char *file1 = "hello_world.txt";
const char *file2 = "copyhello.txt";

int main(void)
    {
    char char_array[BUFMEMSIZE];
    char copied_array[BUFMEMSIZE];
    FILE *fInput, *fOutput;

    fInput = fopen(file1, "r");
    if(fInput != NULL)
        {
        fOutput = fopen(file2, "w");
        if(fOutput != NULL)
            {
            // make sure memory is wiped before use
            memset(char_array, 0, BUFMEMSIZE);
            memset(copied_array, 0, BUFMEMSIZE);
            size_t lastSuccessfulRead = 0;
            // the read-then-loop pattern: try and read 50 chars
            size_t bytesRead = fread(char_array, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, fInput);
            while(bytesRead != 0)
                {
                // we got at least 1 char ..
                // (to be used at end - so we know where in char_array is the last byte read)
                lastSuccessfulRead = bytesRead;
                // 'bytesRead' bytes were read : copy to other array
                strncpy(copied_array, char_array, bytesRead);
                // write to output file, number of bytes read
                fwrite(copied_array, sizeof(char), bytesRead, fOutput);
                // read more, and loop, see if we got any more chars
                bytesRead = fread(char_array, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, fInput);
                }
            // set char after the last-read-in char to null, as a string-terminator.
            char_array[lastSuccessfulRead] = '\0';
            // an array of chars is also a 'string'
            printf("char_array:   %s\n", char_array);
            fclose(fOutput);
            }
        else printf("cant open %s\n", file2);
        fclose(fInput);
        }
    else printf("cant open %s\n", file1);
    }
```